# Open Source Model or dataset for attention map visualization

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, machine-learning-model, visualization

Helloo (:

I'm trying to develop a python application where users can upload an image e.g. of their website and receive a heatmap or attention map in return. This map should indicate where users are likely to focus their attention on the image.

I'm seeking:

- Existing models suitable for generating attention maps for website
  images.
- Publicly available datasets with eye-tracking data or similar information for website images, which could be used to train such a
  model.

The functionality I aim for is similar to what's offered by Zyro's AI Heatmap or Attention Insight.

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!